# duplicate component in vue3 webpage?

Tags: vue.js, components

In my app I intend to present two minigames on a single page. For starters I copied Memory-game component to a new component NamesByPictures.
I try to present them both but I see only one game on my webbpage ( while html shows the duplicate code)
Does anyone see what I am missing here?

```
<template>
<div class="custom-container-fixed">
    

    <Memory key="2"></Memory>
    
    <NamesByPictures key="1"></NamesByPictures>

</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more code details? For example the `Memory` and `NamesByPictures` components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use simply use two times the Memory Component and rather duplicate the code and put it in a new component?

Other than that.
Are they maybe positioned on top of each other via `position: absolute`? Because you say you see them in the DOM. Or could one be hidden somehow else?

Comment: ahh, yess. That is it, position fixed... Thanks for pointing this out.